# Getting different python version between docker run and build

Tags: python, docker, centos7

I'm trying to build a python image using the [official centos python 2.7 image](https://hub.docker.com/r/centos/python-27-centos7/tags) as a base:

When I run the base image via a bash shell, I get a different python version from when docker tries to build it from my dockerfile.

Example:

```
docker system prune    # clean slate
docker pull centos/python-27-centos7:latest
docker run -it centos/python-27-centos7:latest /bin/bash
which python
> /opt/app-root/bin/python
python --version
> Python 2.7.16
exit
```

So... open a bash shell onto the base image, and I've got python 2.7.16 installed.

Contents of `app.dockerfile`:

```
FROM centos/python-27-centos7:latest
RUN which python
RUN python --version
RUN pip install -U pip
```

When I build the dockerfile:

```
docker build --no-cache -f app.dockerfile .
```

I get this output:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  14.34kB
Step 1/7 : FROM centos/python-27-centos7:2.7
 ---> 55ede294318e
Step 2/7 : RUN which python
 ---> Running in 2c1c217dc7a2
/opt/app-root/bin/python
Removing intermediate container 2c1c217dc7a2
 ---> 7f3692a71370
Step 3/7 : RUN python --version
 ---> Running in 12cfab19a44d
Python 2.7.5
Removing intermediate container 12cfab19a44d
 ---> 7d354cadd2af
Step 4/7 : RUN pip install -U pip
 ---> Running in 4d58f3999602
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/app-root/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
    from pip import main
  File "/opt/app-root/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    import logging
  File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    import sys, os, time, cStringIO, traceback, warnings, weakref, collections
  File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/weakref.py", line 14, in <module>
    from _weakref import (
ImportError: cannot import name _remove_dead_weakref
The command '/bin/sh -c pip install -U pip' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

The image is now reporting that python - on the *exact same path* - is at 2.7.5. And when I get to the `pip install` command, it fails because of a bug that's present in 2.7.5 but resolved by 2.7.16.

Why am I seeing this difference? What's different about running a bash shell onto an image, and running build steps on it?

Comment: It seems that you're using a different tag? The shell one you are using `latest` and the dockerfile is using `2.7`.

Comment: Ach, sorry. Was trying different versions and pasted the wrong output. I've tried both `latest` and `2.7`.
It actually seems that I'm using the image incorrectly - https://hub.docker.com/r/centos/python-27-centos7/ - it seems it's an "S2I base image", intended to be built using source-to-image. No idea what that means but I guess that's why it's behaving unexpectedly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my comment above - seems I was using a different type of image to what I thought I was.